# Scanner not scanning all fields?

Tags: java

I was writing my first, well second if you count hello world, program and ran into a small issue.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is your name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("What is your favorite number: ");
    int favoriteNumber = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is your favorite game: ");
    String game = scan.nextLine();
}
}
```

So it scans in name and favoriteNumber but the program ends before asking the user to enter a favorite game. Essentially the user can only enter text twice instead of three times like I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:  `scan.nextInt()` does not consume the trailing newline character after the user presses enter.  The subsequent call to `scan.nextLine()` then finds a newline character waiting.

Try switching out `int favoriteNumber = scan.nextInt();` for `String favoriteNumber = scan.nextLine();` to see if that fixes the issue.  If it does, my hypothesis is correct.

If that *is* the case, then you should probably use `Integer.parseInt` to convert this string into an integer.  The problem here is effectively that you really want to collect 3 lines of input, where a line is defined as "any sequence of characters ending with a newline". Your program is currently written to request a line, an int, then a line, rather than "3 lines of input, one of which contains an int".

Comment: +1 Other way is to invoke `scan.nextLine()` right after `nextInt();` to consume remaining new line mark (this way is not so clear as `int favoriteNumber = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())` but is good to confirm root of the problem).

Comment: True, that might be a nice simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

an exception must be thrown in here scan.nextInt();
Check  whether you entered a proper int